# Why does a print command produce a beep?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, windows-7, beep

Odd question; I got this to work by accident and have narrowed it down to the following:

```
myPath = "c:\abc"
print myPath
```

Why does this cause the PC to beep? I'm using on Windows 7, dragging the script into a command prompt window.

Comment: Because `\a` is the [bell ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character), and not just a backslash character and the letter `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wouldn't say it was a duplicate tough, as I get no error; just the bell sound.

Comment: No, but the issue is exactly the same; you used unescaped backslashes in a string literal, where ``\`` plus something else has special meaning.

Comment: I would have got there eventually :)

Comment: The reason is the same as in my answer to your yesterdays question...